# Uml about the association and the aggregation in my project

Tags: java, associations, uml, aggregation

I'm doing this little project for an exam. My teacher pay attention about the uml so my problem is about the aggregation and association in my project (i know this is a question asked a lot of times). 
The project is a global observer which has a collection of Component and everytime a Component (Leaf or Composite) changes its state, it notifies to the observer. My question is about the correctness of the aggregation between ConcreteObserver and Component: ConcreteObserver has a collection of Component, but  each Component has a reference to the observer (in Leaf and Composite there is an observer). Maybe I should add an association Component->ConcreteObserver?
Maybe I should change the aggregation ConcreteObserver 1->* Component into an association  ConcreteObserver1->*Com

Here is the uml
[image]

And here is the whole code of my project I know it's long but you have to pay attention on Concrete Observer and the Concrete Component (Composite)
(I don't put the leaf because it's very similar to Composite but it hasn't the children related method implemented)
Here is the Component

```
//Component
public interface Component {
    public void op();
    public void add(Component c);
    public void remove(Component c);
    public List <Component> getChild();   
    public void setState(int x);
    public int getState();
    public String getName();
}


//Composite
public class Composite implements Component {
    private int state;
    private String name;
    private Observer observer;
    private List <Component> comps = new ArrayList <Component> ();

    public Composite(String name, Observer observer){
        this.name = name;
        this.observer = observer;
        this.observer.add(this);              
    }

    @Override
    public void setState(int x){
        this.state = x;
        observer.update(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getState(){
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void op() {
        System.out.println("sono una foglia");
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Component c) {
        comps.add(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Component c) {
        comps.remove(c);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Component> getChild() {
        List <Component> cc = new ArrayList <Component> ();
        for (Component zen : comps){
            cc.add(zen);
        }
        return cc;
    }   
}


//Observer
public abstract class Observer {   
    public abstract void update(String name);    
    public abstract void add(Component c);
}


//ConcreteObserver
public class ConcreteObserver extends Observer {
    private List <Component> components = new ArrayList <Component> ();

    @Override
    public void update(String name){
        for(Component zen : components){
            if(zen.getName()==name){
                System.out.println("the state of " + name + " is changed, now it's " + zen.getState());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Component c){
        components.add(c);
    }

    public void printAllState(){
        for(Component zen : components){ 
            System.out.println("the state of " + zen.getName() + " is " + zen.getState());
        }
    }
}


//main
public class Compito24Febbraio2017 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteObserver o = new ConcreteObserver();
        Composite c1 = new Composite ("c1",o);
        Leaf l1 = new Leaf("l1",o);
        Leaf l2 = new Leaf("l2",o);
        c1.add(l1);
        c1.add(l2);
        c1.setState(5);
        l1.setState(4);
        o.printAllState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't care about those shared aggregations. Leave them away or if they are there, just ignore them. The UML spec says (p. 110):

> Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

Which effectively means: it has no specific meaning.

**Edit** as to your comment: The preferred way to represent the relation is this:

[image]

You use role names at the opposite side of the association rather than typed attributes.

Comment: I really don't understand, I have to ignore the aggregation? So I have to eliminate the aggregation between ConcreteObserver and Component?

Comment: It makes no difference if it's there or not. A shared aggregation has no agreed semantics.

Comment: This is because I put in the ConcreteObserver a collection of component, so the aggregation is a little bit redundant right?

Comment: Ok I have understood now, the shared aggregation link can be changed with an association and the aggregation it's just like a placebo. We could never use aggregation and always use association (not the opposite). This link has illuminate me http://aviadezra.blogspot.it/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html

Comment: By the way I write again because I think that in my class Diagram there are some redundant informations. The ConcreteObserver has a private collection of Component, so it's a little bit redundant an 1 to many association. I should get rid of the collection and leave only a 1 to many association. Am I right?